# How can i iterate an array in javascript using blaze templates of meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hello everyone i'm trying to iterate an array in javascript using blaze templates of meteor.js.

When I set a static value into array, ex: 6, the filled of this work really fine but when I set 'i' var in array no work at all. like this:

```
......."titulo": "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].titulo_pub}}{{/each}}"}.....
```

But when i set a 'i' var no work

```
......."citas": '{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].citas}}{{/each}}',......
```

.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= {{#each scraper}}{{c_titulos}}{{/each}}; i++) {
        sample_data[i] = {"citas": '{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].citas}}{{/each}}',
                          "autores": '{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[i].authors}}{{/each}}',
                          "titulo": "{{#each scraper}}{{publicaciones.[6].titulo_pub}}{{/each}}"}
        sample_data.fill(sample_data[i], i, i + 1);
      }
```

If run this code and calling this object with console.log, console shows me the below message:[image]

Like i use a static value like '6', all elements of this array had the same "titulo".

Please if you could help me i'll be so grateful. Thanks so much to all. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaze handles the iteration and the scope of each iteration for you. e.g.

```
{{#each scrape in scraper}}
  {{scrape.titulo}}
  {{scrape.citas}}
  {{scrape.autores}}
{{/each}}
```

c.f. http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in